# How do you adapt your nodes position to landscape & portrait

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, position, orientation

Im trying to make a game board that is universal and can be played on ipad/iphones either in portrait or landscape. The tiles looks fine in portrait but when i switch to landscape it gets cut off. How can i make sure the board will always be centered?

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

let numRows = 7
let numCols = 7
var counter = 0
let squareSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width/7, height: view.bounds.width/7)

for row in 0..<numRows{
    for col in 0..<numCols {
        if counter == 49 {
            break
        }
        let spriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "piece\(counter)")
        spriteNode.size = squareSize
        spriteNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0-(frame.width*0.43)+(CGFloat(col)*spriteNode.size.width), y: -CGFloat(row)*spriteNode.size.height + frame.height/3 )
        addChild(spriteNode)
        counter = counter+1
    }
}
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
    if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        view.presentScene(scene)
    }
    view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    view.showsFPS = true
    view.showsNodeCount = true
}
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would change the Scene scale mode from `scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill` to `scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit`. In a game the SKView frame size is not required and you can work within your own coordinate space (size property of the scene) e.g. set to 100 x 100. -> Interface Builder setting.

Don't relate anything on the view frame/bounds of the SKView. The code from your scene controller should work then as below, all related to the size of the scene.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let numRows = 7
    let numCols = 7
    var counter = 0
    let squareSize = CGSize(width: size.width/7, height: size.width/7)

    for row in 0..<numRows{
        for col in 0..<numCols {
            if counter == 49 {
                break
            }
            let spriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "piece\(counter)")
            spriteNode.size = squareSize
            spriteNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0-(size.width*0.43)+(CGFloat(col)*spriteNode.size.width), y: -CGFloat(row)*spriteNode.size.height + size.height/3 )
            addChild(spriteNode)
            counter = counter+1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It adds a black bar around the screen which isn't exactly what i want.

Comment: @xxFlashxx The black border which is visible in your screenshots as well ?. I explained you how to to use the SKScene coordinate system to center the Nodes in your scene.